# Testing a list of URLs with Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have limited understanding about cron commands,
I have tried using one particular url, but I would like the script to get a comma delimited list of URL’s and check their http response every 5 minutes for 30 minutes. Then output the result.
My guess is:

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget "www.example.com" --timeout 30 -O - 2>/dev/null  | \
          grep "Normal operation string" || echo "The site is down" | \
          /usr/bin/mail -v -s "Site is down" your@e-mail.address
```

But it works for one particular predefined website only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're rather limiting yourself by trying to fit this onto one line. Just put your commands into a script, save it somewhere as executable, and then call that script from the `cron` file.

To get multiple sites, just set them up in an array and then iterate over it:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a sites
sites=("www.example.com" "www.example.org" "www.example.net")
for site in "${sites[@]}"; do
    if ! wget "$site" --timeout 30 -O - 2> /dev/null | grep "Normal operation string"; then
        echo "The site is down" | mail -v -s "Site is down"  email@example.com
    fi
done
```

Or you can read them in from a file. This assumes they are stored in `sites.txt`, one site per line:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r site; do
    if ! wget "$site" --timeout 30 -O - 2> /dev/null | grep "Normal operation string"; then
        echo "The site is down" | mail -v -s "Site is down"  email@example.com
    fi
done < sites.txt
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. @miken32

But the script that you provided would again be limited to predefined number of website.

Comment: @Shabbir, you should be able to replace the initialization of `sites` with a suitable use of `read -a` or similar to adapt it to your own purposes.

Comment: There's no need to put the sites in an array; just loop ojer them directly: `for site in "www.example.com" "www.example.net"`...

Comment: @tripleee that's correct, but it can make for a very long `for` statement.